# Access 2010 - Conditional Formatting Many Fields

Tags: usability, ms-access-2010, conditional-formatting

I need to conditional format 24 text boxes with 2 rules each.  Each rule is slightly different, based on the month.  Is there some way I can type my conditional format rules all in one screen so I don't have to click so many buttons?  Plus, this would save considerable time if I even needed to edit the rules.  Psuedocode:

```
Style1 = FontFill.Red
Style2 = FontFill.Yellow

txtField1.ConditionalFormatting.Add("<rule text>", Style1)
txtField1.ConditionalFormatting.Add("<rule text>", Style2)

txtField2.ConditionalFormatting.Add("<rule text>", Style1)
txtField2.ConditionalFormatting.Add("<rule text>", Style2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FormatConditions.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194814%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in place of your pseudo code.  With "Form3" open in Design View, I did the following in the Immediate window:

```vb
Forms("Form3").Controls("txtNote").FormatConditions.Add acFieldValue, acBetween, 10, 100
Forms("Form3").Controls("txtNote").FormatConditions(0).ForeColor = vbRed
' confirm the FormatCondition is enabled ...
? Forms("Form3").Controls("txtNote").FormatConditions(0).Enabled
True
```

Then inspecting the format condition from the form property gave me this ...

[image: Conditional Formatting screen shot]

For 24 controls, you could create a procedure to apply the conditional formats.  Modify the procedure when the rules change.  Or store the rules in a table and have the procedure read the rules from the table.

Comment: Thanks for sending me in the right direction.  I ended up using VBA in the OnPrint event for the section I was interested in.  I just wrote my rules in code and then set the .BackColor ... rather than using FormatConditions.